# Sharepoint SPFX - external javascript loading issue

Tags: sharepoint, spfx

I have followed the [quick start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part) and made a working hello world webpart.

I want to include the twitter widget, so I have followed the guide on adding external JavaScript, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/add-jqueryui-accordion-to-web-part) is linked from git hub

I add the following to my config.json

```
"externals": {
  "widgets":"https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
},
```

and I import with

```
import 'widgets';
```

But, I get the following error

```
***Failed to load component "ab3668f3-39a2-4b40-a307-a1bea4023df9" (TwitterWebPart).
Original error: ***Failed to load URL 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' for resource 'widgets' in component 'ab3668f3-39a2-4b40-a307-a1bea4023df9' (TwitterWebPart). There was a network problem.
This may be a problem with a HTTPS certificate. Make sure you have the right certificate.
```

The url `https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are 2 issues here.

`This may be a problem with a HTTPS certificate.` - this error looks to be from twitter's end and we can't do anything about it.

Secondly, the `widgets.js` is non-AMD. So, you need to load it a bit differently.

Reference - [Loading a non-AMD module](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/spfx/web-parts/basics/add-an-external-library.md#loading-a-non-amd-module)

To fix these issues , I downloaded the `https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js` file locally and added it in another folder.

After that, I modified the `config.json` as below:

```
"externals": {    
      "widgets": {
          "path": "scripts/widgets.js",
          "globalName": "twttr"
      }  
  },
```

Here, I created a folder named `scripts` at the root of the solution and added the js file there.

Modify your import statement and add replace it as below:

```
require("widgets");
```

As content is injected into the page, your twitter feed will not show, add the follow code to load your tweets

```
public constructor() {
  super();
  let w= require("widgets");
  setTimeout( () => w.widgets.load(), 0);
}
```

My folder structure is as below:

[image]

Now, run gulp serve, it will work correctly.